# Angular i18n for text containing routerLink and requires different word order

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-i18n

I am struggling to find the most efficient way to translate the text containing routerLink or text where some words should be wrapped in html tags ( **word** ).

Let's see how it looks **without** the i18n implementation:

**example.component.html**

```
<div>
 Hello and welcome to this test example. In order to proceed click on this 
 <a [routerLink]="['settings/subscription']">Link</a>
</div>
```

Now let's add **i18n** to it, and use one possible approach to deal with the routerLink:
en.json

```
{
  "WELCOME_LABEL": "Hello and welcome to this test example. In order to proceed click on this,
  "LINK_LABEL": "link"
}
```

**example.component.html**

```
<div>
 {{'WELCOME_LABEL' | translate}} 
 <a [routerLink]="['settings/subscription']">{{'LINK_LABEL' | translate}}</a>
</div>
```

The problem with this approach is that different languages could have words in a different order. For example. ***"Please click on this link"*** in some other language could have the order where **"*link*"** is at the begining or in the middle of a sentence.

> Is there some general / official approach to deal with this situation?

The one way how I could solve it is to get the current locale in the component and then do the if check in the template based on it.

I don't like this way because I'm kind of stepping out of i18n practice, and creating separate JSON objects based on locale just to be able to fit the word ordering needs.

**example.component.ts**

```
constructor(
    @Inject( LOCALE_ID ) protected localeId: string
) {
    console.log(this.localeId);
}
```

**example.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="localeId === 'en-Us'">
 {{'WELCOME_LABEL_EN' | translate}} 
 <a [routerLink]="['settings/subscription']">{{'LINK_LABEL_EN' | translate}}</a>
</div>
<div *ngIf="localeId === 'otherLanguage'">
 {{'WELCOME_LABEL_1_OTHER' | translate}} 
 <a [routerLink]="['settings/subscription']">{{'LINK_LABEL_OTHER' | translate}}</a>
 {{'WELCOME_LABEL_2_OTHER' | translate}} 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you simply define the `<div>` in three parts? Like, the text beginning, the link, then the end.

```
<div>
  {{'WELCOME_LABEL_START' | translate}}
  <a [routerLink]="['settings/subscription']">{{'LINK_LABEL' | translate}}</a>
  {{'WELCOME_LABEL_END' | translate}}
</div>
```

This way, according to the language, you just have to define the sentence in two parts.

```
{
  "WELCOME_LABEL_START": "In order to proceed, click on this,
  "LINK_LABEL": "link",
  "WELCOME_LABEL_END": " whatever language you have."
}
```

And you just let the start / end empty if unnecessary.

Comment: Appreciate the idea, definitely more reliable than my solution

Comment: I'd be glad if you accept the answer, in case the solution is good enough for you :)

Comment: An issue occurs for any language that may then change word order.

Comment: No, I don't see any trouble. It's up to you to correctly define your i18n files.

Answer (score 1):

Angular doesn't seem to support passing directive and none-HTML element as `innerHTML`. I don't try it, but it  needs to be noticed.

---

You can pass the whole sentence as `innerHTML` for the translation, which includs the link element. In this way, you can output the content dynamically.

Template:

```html
<span [innerHTML]="key | translate"></span>
```

JSON:

```
{
  "key": "Please click on <a href='abc.com'>this link</a>."
}
```

Comment: But then you are maintaining code in your translation files.  If the href needs to change, or you need to add a class, or do any other changes to that element, you have to change it in all those files (one per language).

Comment: @Roobot You are right. Unless the order of words really matters, otherwise, splitting  the sentence into three parts (three slots for translation) is more convenient for maintenance.